# JBoss AS 7 upgrade to Java 7, JBoss VFS

Tags: spring, jboss, jboss7.x, java-7, vfs

We have an spring application which dynamically loads components based in the lib folder.

This application needs to be deployed on different AS, like Jetty,Tomcat,JBoss..

Now, JBoss has this VFS feature, where it does not really unpack your war it seems, and uses `vfs://` for files inside the war/jar..

Currently we are in the process of upgrading (from Java6) to Java7, and we encounter the following problem.

First of all, snowdrop 1.0.0GA no longer works under Java7, because the InputStream was changed somehow.. Upgrading to snowdrop 2.0.4.Final resolved this issue.

Next up is this gem of a stacktrace:

```
11:37:44,563 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/runtime]] (MSC service thread 1-1) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from "/C:/Tools/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/Aquima-Server-9-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/classes/aquima-config.xml"; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null path
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]

.....................

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null path
    at org.jboss.spring.vfs.VFSServletContextResourcePatternResolver.convertClassLoaderURL(VFSServletContextResourcePatternResolver.java:62) [snowdrop-vfs-2.0.4.Final.jar:2.0.4.Final]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.findAllClassPathResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:305) [spring-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.getResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:270) [spring-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getResources(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1245) [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]

.........................

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null path
    at org.jboss.vfs.VFS.getChild(VFS.java:187) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VFS.getChild(VFS.java:173) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VFS.getChild(VFS.java:154) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
    at org.jboss.spring.vfs.VFSUtil.invokeMethodWithExpectedExceptionType(VFSUtil.java:157) [snowdrop-vfs-2.0.4.Final.jar:2.0.4.Final]
    at org.jboss.spring.vfs.VFSUtil.invokeVfsMethod(VFSUtil.java:170) [snowdrop-vfs-2.0.4.Final.jar:2.0.4.Final]
    at org.jboss.spring.vfs.VFSServletContextResourcePatternResolver.convertClassLoaderURL(VFSServletContextResourcePatternResolver.java:59) [snowdrop-vfs-2.0.4.Final.jar:2.0.4.Final]
    ... 34 more
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: The stack trace is actually nice :)

Comment: Are you sure that Spring doesn't pass `null` as one of values to JBoss Spring + VFS integration code? Could be worth debugging and figure out where the null comes from.

Comment: Also, could you please try with [JBoss EAP 6.1](http://www.jboss.org/products/eap)?